# Define a constant, then retrieve it from a different scope

Tags: php, wordpress

If you define a constant in Wordpress on file_1.php

define( 'SOMETHING', location );

how can I use this in file_2.php?

If I define it again it sends a "Constant already defined" error. But if I don't define it, it doesn't know what it is. If it detects that it already exists, there must be a way to access it. 
Is there a way I can access it from file_2.php?

SOMETHING = a specific URL, and I'm trying to use it in file_2,php to load a script,, "wp_register_script('script', SOMETHING . '/filename.css')"

If I don't define SOMETHING again and try to use it in "wp_register_script" it says "Use of undefined constant SOMETHING - assumed 'SOMETHING'"

Thanks

Comment: How are you trying to refer to it? Show us the code.

Comment: echo `SOMETHING` in file_2.php.

Comment: Just trying to use it in another location to load a script,, "wp_register_script('script', SOMETHING . '/filename')"

Comment: @user2413333: Try `echo SOMETHING` first.

Comment: I can echo it,but I can't use it to register scripts

Comment: If I don't define it again and try to use it in "wp_register_script" it says "Use of undefined constant SOMETHING - assumed 'SOMETHING'"

Comment: Well, I guess because `functions.php` doesn't know about `file_1.php`?

Comment: @user2413333: So, your problem is different from what you stated in the original question. What happens when you try to define a different constant and use it with `wp_register_script`? Does it work?

Comment: Yes it does, but redefining it seems like it isn't being done properly, or does it not matter?

Comment: psst… auto_prepend_file …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to place the `Define()` in a file that *every* script will come across in WordPress (i.e. a file that's always included, `wp-config.php` for site-wide definitions).

If you were to define a constant in one file, it doesn't necessarily mean that the other pages automatically knows it exists, until it's '**included**'.

At the top of `functions.php` to make sure it's always going to use `SOMETHING`, you can see if it exists first:

```
if ( !defined( 'SOMETHING' )) {
    define( 'SOMETHING', 'location/here/folder' );
}
```

For Testing purposes, before trying to use register_script - save your expected string to a variable.

```
<?php
    $ScriptLocation = SOEMTHING . '/filename.css';
    echo $ScriptLocation; 
?>
```